# ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION not automatically granted on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm checking if application has `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission granted because of Android M. As far as I know, device with version lower than Marshmallow automatically grants all permissions with installation.

However, if I add this piece of code, it returns `false` on Android 5.1.1

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Is it because the device, I am using for testing, has completely disabled access to location for all apps?

Comment: Is the permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in your manifest, and your target API on api 23 or greater?

Comment: It is in Manifest and targetSdkVersion is 25, minSdkVersion is 15

Comment: Hmm very odd. i dont know without more code but as a work around you could do
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

Comment: The thing is that if I do not ask for that permission at all, it works ok. But if I try that as shown above, it is evaluated as false.

Comment: Instead of Access Coars Location use Fine Location and your problem would be solved in 6> Devices

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Use this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

For Below 6.0 Devices You will get Permission Denied(-1) if you check with Coarse Location.

Answer (score -1):

Actually Android minimum sdk version 21-22 i.e. 5.0 doesn't need to check permission but when we have to Test the our app on different phones for eg. on minimum sdk version 23 i.e. on Marshmallow. You need to check permission externally in your App.

Write below code in Your Starting_Activity

```
//requesting Permission
private void requestingPermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)){
        //Exaplian here why you need this permission
    }
    //Ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ 
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, },STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

Now Add another

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    //checking the request code of Permission request
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Dont forget call below method in your activity onCreate() Method

```
requestingPermission();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I know how to request permissions. I just don't understand why I do not have permissions automatically granted on Android 5.1.1

Comment: @JakubGruber  I already told that  on Android 5.1.1 we do not need handle the permissions separately  it will handle by them-self..  But on  Marshmallow  we have to tell Android sdk  we are going to use xyz permission in our app

Comment: Yes, but this permissions is not granted on my phone and what I'm trying to find out is why. Because it should be

Comment: @JakubGruber please follow this link     https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-control-app-permissions-on-Android-5-1-1-smartphones

Comment: He is correct. Coarse Location in 5.1 says denied and not granted by default. You found any solution